# How to prevent form submission until form is filled using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

It should not be possible to submit the form if the user does not enter a value into the text entry fields, e.g. for surname or company, and at least one event has not been selected
(remember that users don’t always fill out forms in top to bottom order). Here is the sample code from php file which I can't edit. Only java script must be used.

```
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
    <section id="bookEvents">
        <h2>Select Events</h2>
    <div class="item">
                <span class="eventTitle">Thomas Bewick and His Apprentices</span>
                <span class="eventPrice">0.00</span>
                <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="1" data-price="0.00"></span>
                </div>
    <div class="item">
                <span class="eventTitle">Winter Festival @ Discovery Museum</span>
                <span class="eventPrice">0.00</span>
                <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="12" data-price="0.00"></span>
                </div>
        </section>
        <section id="collection">
            <h2>Collection method</h2>
            <p>Please select whether you want your chosen event ticket(s) to be delivered to your home address (a charge applies for this) or whether you want to collect them yourself.</p>
            <p>
            Home address - £5.99 <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" data-price="5.99" checked="">&nbsp; | &nbsp;
            Collect from ticket office - no charge <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="ticketOffice" data-price="0">
            </p>
        </section>

        <section id="makeBooking">
            <h2>Make booking</h2>
            Your details
            Customer Type: <select name="customerType">
                <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
                <option value="ret">Customer</option>
                <option value="trd">Trade</option>
            </select>

            <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
                Forename <input type="text" name="forename">
                Surname <input type="text" name="surname">
            </div>
            <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
                Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName">
            </div>
            <p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;" id="termsText">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
            <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>

            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book now!" disabled=""></p>
        </section>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using `HTMLFormElement.elements` to dynamically set `required` attribute:

Just use the **[HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)** property to get all the form controls (input, select, etc) inside your form and then use the **[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** method to get a shallow-copied array of the *HTMLFormControlsCollection* which you can now loop over and use the **[setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)** method to dynamically set a `required` attribute to all the form controls.

Check and run the following Code Snippet or open this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/vey9un4w/4/)** link for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
// get the form
const form = document.getElementById("bookingForm");

// get the form controls
let x = form.elements;

// Convert the list of form controls to an array and set the required attribute to each control
Array.from(x).forEach(e => {
 e.setAttribute("required", ""); 
})
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
  <section id="bookEvents">
    <h2>Select Events</h2>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="eventTitle">Thomas Bewick and His Apprentices</span>
      <span class="eventPrice">0.00</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="1" data-price="0.00"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="eventTitle">Winter Festival @ Discovery Museum</span>
      <span class="eventPrice">0.00</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="12" data-price="0.00"></span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="collection">
    <h2>Collection method</h2>
    <p>Please select whether you want your chosen event ticket(s) to be delivered to your home address (a charge applies for this) or whether you want to collect them yourself.</p>
    <p>
      Home address - £5.99 <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" data-price="5.99" checked="">&nbsp; | &nbsp;
      Collect from ticket office - no charge <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="ticketOffice" data-price="0">
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="makeBooking">
    <h2>Make booking</h2>
    Your details
    Customer Type: <select name="customerType">
    <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
    <option value="ret">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd">Trade</option>
    </select>

    <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
      Forename <input type="text" name="forename">
      Surname <input type="text" name="surname">
    </div>
    <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
      Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName">
    </div>
    <p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;" id="termsText">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
      <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book now!"></p>
  </section>
</form>
```

### Using `required`:

Just add a `required` attribute to each input element like this:

```
<input type="text" name="forename" required>
<input type="text" name="forename" required>

<select name="customerType" required>
  <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
  <option value="ret">Customer</option>
  <option value="trd">Trade</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit html, this should be done only with java script.

Comment: and a small info there are two events in the list, user should choose at least one and choosing every event is not mandatory

Comment: @Gokul Check the other answer that I have posted.

Comment: its saying that in line  btn.addEventListener("click", verifyEvents); addEventListener is undefined

Comment: @Gokul Make sure your script tag that has the js is loaded at the end of yout page content otherwise your js will be loaded before the html is even present on the page leading to errors like that one. Move your script to the bottom of your page just above the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

1_you can add `required` attribute to inputs by JS. :)

2_I'm not a pro and the only way I can think of , is using AJAX and JQuery .like this:

```
<script>
function echo() {
var name = $("#id");
if (name.val() === "") {
    alert(name.attr('placeholder') + " is empty");
    return;
}

$.ajax({
    url: "your destination",
    data: {
        name: name.val(),
    },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data['error'] === false) {
            alert(data['msg']);
        } else {
            alert(data['msg']);
        }
    }

});
}
</script
```

you need JQ just for the AJAX part of course, but the rest of the function can get done 
 just by JS.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try and get access to your html and change it's structure e.g. the "Select Events" section could use a `<select>` dropdown instead of the current two checkboxes so you can make use of the cleaner and more concise `required` attribute approach shown in the other answer that I posted.

However, if you HAVE to use only JavaScript to validate the form, then you can just retrieve the form elements, validate each element and submit the form if they all pass.

To do that, you can just replace the current `<input type="submit">` element with a `<button>` instead and then add a click listener to that button which in turn will run a function that will prevent the form from submitting using [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method, check and validate each form element and submit the form if all the elements pass the validation.

---

Check and run the following Code Snippet or open this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/vey9un4w/36/) for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("bookingForm");
const events = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="event[]"]');
const terms = document.querySelector('input[name="termsChkbx"]');
const selectBox = document.querySelector('select[name="customerType"]');
const fName = document.querySelector('input[name="forename"]');
const sName = document.querySelector('input[name="surname"]');
const btn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

function verifyEvents(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if(selectBox.value != "" && terms.checked && fName.value != "" && sName != "" && (events[0].checked || events[1].checked)){
   console.log(selectBox.value);
  form.submit();
 } else {
   alert("Please fill the form.");
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", verifyEvents);
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
    <section id="bookEvents">
        <h2>Select Events</h2>
    <div class="item">
                <span class="eventTitle">Thomas Bewick and His Apprentices</span>
                <span class="eventPrice">0.00</span>
                <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="1" data-price="0.00"></span>
                </div>
    <div class="item">
                <span class="eventTitle">Winter Festival @ Discovery Museum</span>
                <span class="eventPrice">0.00</span>
                <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="12" data-price="0.00"></span>
                </div>
        </section>
        <section id="collection">
            <h2>Collection method</h2>
            <p>Please select whether you want your chosen event ticket(s) to be delivered to your home address (a charge applies for this) or whether you want to collect them yourself.</p>
            <p>
            Home address - £5.99 <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" data-price="5.99" checked="">&nbsp; | &nbsp;
            Collect from ticket office - no charge <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="ticketOffice" data-price="0">
            </p>
        </section>

        <section id="makeBooking">
            <h2>Make booking</h2>
            Your details
            Customer Type: <select name="customerType">
                <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
                <option value="ret">Customer</option>
                <option value="trd">Trade</option>
            </select>

            <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
                Forename <input type="text" name="forename">
                Surname <input type="text" name="surname">
            </div>
            <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
                Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName">
            </div>
            <p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;" id="termsText">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
            <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>

<p><button id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Book now!">Book now!</button></p>
        </section>
    </form>
```